# Rails - Controller Naming Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Project & Permissions Model.

In my app I want to have 2 dialogs, for creating permissions, modifying permissions and viewing permissions for a project.

What controller/methods should I be using to not make a mess of the Rails framework's intention?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might need is a `ProjectsController` and a `PermissionsController` to keep things simple, but ensure that the route to the Permission one is nested in your routes:

```
resources :projects do |project|
  project.resources :permissions
end
```

Sometimes it's advantageous to name it `Projects::PermissionsController` to be sure you're not using it on permissions directly by making it clear that the two are closely related:

```
resources :projects do |project|
  project.resources :permissions, :controller => 'projects/permissions'
end
```

In this case the only way to access permissions is by giving it the context of a project, and this applies to routes, too:

```
link_to('Edit', project_permissions_path(@project))
```

Comment: does that route syntax work in rails 3?  I know a lot of route stuff changed between versions 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks Tad, that model setup makes sense. What confuses me is what methods do I use for the 3 use cases listed? creating permissions, modifying permissions and viewing permissions

Comment: @brettish That is the Rails 3 syntax for defining routes. The old way was `map.resources`

Comment: @tadman thanks, I am pretty new to rails 3 and have only used `resources :projects do resources :permissions end` (without the project variable) so it looked a little foreign to me.

Comment: @brettish The way outlined in the answer doesn't need the block variable and functions just peachy keen the way you describe it.  I'd even say your way is the more common approach for Rails 3, at least according to the routing guide.